# Convert AWS output parameters to Ansible dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, dictionary, ansible

so I have output from Ansible in the following format:

```
"parameters": [ 
            {
                "parameter_key": "NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize", 
                "parameter_value": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "parameter_key": "NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity", 
                "parameter_value": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "parameter_key": "NodeInstanceType", 
                "parameter_value": "c5.large"
            }, 
            {
                "parameter_key": "NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize", 
                "parameter_value": "4"
            }
        ]
```

I would like to convert it to ....

```
"_params": {
        
            "NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize": "1"
        , 
        
            "NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity": "1"
        , 
        
            "NodeInstanceType": "c5.large"
        , 
        
            "NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize": "4"
        }
```

How would I begin to crack this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter for this apparently ...

```
"{{parameters|items2dict(key_name='parameter_key', value_name='parameter_value')}}"
```

does the exact conversion I desired.